# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Stylesheet.create')

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am getting is pesky error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Stylesheet.create')' as can be seen in the screenshot as well.

[image]

Following is the code I am using;

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, Stylesheet} from 'react-native';
import {Content, Container, Body, Title} from 'native-base';
import GoogleStaticMap from 'react-native-google-static-map';

export default class Contact extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleStaticMap
      style={styles.map}
      latitude={'32.064171'}
      longitude={'34.7748068'}
      zoom={13}
      size={{
      width: 300,
      height: 550
    }}
    />);
  }
}

const styles = Stylesheet.create({
  map: {
    width: 300,
    height: 550
  }
});

module.export = Contact;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `StyleSheet` with upper case on Sheet.

```
import {Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
```

Comment: Ofcourse, thank you so much, how could I miss that one, cheers again for the help.

Comment: I couldnt believe I fell for this upper-case mistake :D

Answer (score 3):

I was doing ...

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react';
```

But I should do

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 2):

so there is wrong import of stylesheet that  you have made from `react-native`, that is why you are getting that error.

instead you should import as

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
```

and use it as

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    width: 300,
    height: 550
  }
});
```